# Everything but the CSS loading in web application deployed with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and integrated with TeamCity

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, teamcity, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a sails JS application that I deployed using AWS ElasticBeanstalk and set up continuous integration with TeamCity, but (as it says in the title), everything works great except for some reason, the CSS doesn't load.

When I inspect element anything on it, the CSS is there, but it still doesn't show on the page even when I reload. It also works without the teamcity integration.